# imageWithCGImage and memory

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-graphics

If I use `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:]`, passing in a `CGImageRef`, do I then release the `CGImageRef` or does UIImage take care of this itself when it is deallocated?

The documentation isn't entirely clear. It says "This method does not cache the image object."

Originally I called `CGImageRelease` on the CGImageRef after passing it to `imageWithCGImage:`, but that caused a `malloc_error_break` warning in the Simulator claiming a double-free was occurring.

Comment: I suggest filing a documentation bug at https://bugreport.apple.com/ to ask them to clarify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you -- the documentation is muddled at best for this API. Based on your experiences, then, I would conclude that you are responsible for the lifetime of both objects - the `UIImage` and the `CGImageRef`. On top of that you have to make sure the lifetime of the `CGImageRef` is at least as long as the `UIImage` (for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 8):

According to the [fundamental rule of Cocoa memory management](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH), an owning object should release the owned object when it no longer needs it. Other objects are responsible for taking and releasing ownership on their own. If a `UIImage` needs an object to persist but doesn't retain or copy it, it's a bug in `UIImage`'s implementation and should be reported as such.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem in XCode 3.2.1 on Snow Leopard. I have pretty much the same code as Jason.

I have looked at the iPhone sample code which uses `imageWithCGImage` and they always release the `CGImageRef` using `CGImageRelease` after a call to `imageWithCGImage`.

So, is this a bug in the simulator? I always get the `malloc_error_break` warning on the console when I use `CGImageRelease`.

Comment: This should be a comment on Jason's answer, or a new question, as SO isn't a forum.

Comment: I can not comment other people's posts because I do not have enough "reputation". Besides, this isn't a new question. I simply suggested that the problem might only happen in the simulator but not on the device.

Answer (score 2):

The ownership in `UIImage` about `CGImage` is unclear. It seems like don't copy the `CGImage` but it's not guaranteed by documentation. So we have to handle that ourselves.

I used a new subclass of `UIImage` to handle this problem. Just retaining passing `CGImage`, and releasing it when the `dealloc`.

Here is sample.

```
@interface  EonilImage : UIImage
{
    @private
    CGImageRef      sourceImage;
}
- (id)initWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)imageRef scale:(CGFloat)scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation;

@end



@implementation     EonilImage

- (id)initWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)imageRef scale:(CGFloat)scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation
{
    self    =   [super initWithCGImage:imageRef scale:scale orientation:orientation];

    if (self) 
    {
        sourceImage =   imageRef;
        CGImageRetain(imageRef);
    }

    return  self;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    CGImageRelease(sourceImage);
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Because the `CGImage` returned by `-[UIImage CGImage]` property is not guaranteed to be same `CGImage` passed into init method, the class stores `CGImage` separately.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Xcode 3.1 on Snow Leopard? I am experiencing the same issue:

```
CGContextRef ctx = ...;
CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage * newImage = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage] retain];

CGImageRelease(cgImage); // this should be OK, but it now crashes in Simulator on SL
```

I'm guessing that upgrading to Xcode 3.2 will fix the issue.

Comment: As of Xcode 8.1, this works for me. If I don't release the `CGImage`, I get a memory leak, so I assume this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

<>
Not my opinion. I had the same problem. According to documentation

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

imho keeps all references correct. If you are using a CGDataProvider please have a look at
CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback
and set a breakpoint in your callback. You can see that is is correctly called after you [release] your image and you can free() your image data buffer there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I had a similar problem.
I read the answers and then did the following which appears to have fixed it:

```
CGImageRef cgImage = [asset thumbnail];
    UIImage *thumbImage = [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage ]retain];
    UIImageView *thumbImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:thumbImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
```

I used the autorelease as suggested but it was not enough.
One I had added the image to the UIImageView I then released the cgImage.
It didn't crash and deallocated nicely. Why -- I have no idea but it worked.

The asset thumbnail part is from the ALAsset Library by the way, you might need something else there.

Comment: Seems you are leaking thumbImage here, unless you release it elsewhere. UIImageView.initWithImage: will retain the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
"This method does not cache the image object."
```

So the UIImage take the ownership, and thus you should not release the CGImageRef.