# When to release the UIImage?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, cgimage, autorelease

I use the following code to draw a subimage

```
UIImage* subIm = getSubImage( large, rect );
[subIm drawInRect:self.bounds];
```

where `getSubImage` is defined as follows

```
    UIImage* getSubImage(UIImage* uim, CGRect rc){
      CGImageRef imref  = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(uim.CGImage, rc); 
      UIImage*   sub = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imref];
      CGImageRelease(imref);
        NSLog(@"subimage retainCount=%d", [sub  retainCount]); // is 1
      return sub;
   }//getSubImage
```

Is the code correct?

Is it safe to "CGImageRelease" imref?

Has sub "CGImageRetained" imref?

Should I release subIm (I get an error if I do)?

Is subIm contained in the autorelease-pool, and , if so, how do I know this?

In general, can one check if an object is contained in the autorelease pool (for debugging purpose)?

Comment: Do **not** call `retainCount`.  The number returned is generally meaningless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SubIm is enrolled in the AutoRelease Pool because this object is in fact created by the class method imageWithCGImage and that the rule is that instances created by class methods should always return autoreleased instances.

The code is correct though I don't understand why your are using the C syntax instead of the Obj-C syntax to define your function

Comment: Thank you for that rule, it will help! I still wonder if sub has "CGImageRetained" imref... The documentation only says that imref is not cached...

Comment: I thing it has retained it and your are supposed to release it. I have no idea why retainCount is still 1 after CGImageRelease and it might be that CGImageRelease add to release pool.. I don't know ! Check before and after the release maybe ?

Comment: Well, it is the sub-image's retainCount and it should be 1 if it is in the AutoRelease pool. I do not know how to check the retainCount of imref because it is not an objective-c object.

Comment: CGImageCreateWithImageInRect creates an object and you are responsible for releasing it. If you then create an auto released uiimage from it, you are ok to(and should) release the cgimageref(like you are).

Comment: Ultimately it doesn't matter what the retain count of your CGImageRef is-- you created it, therefore you must release it. If the UIImage wants to keep it around, then it's UIImage's responsibility to do so by retaining or copying it, not yours. For example, UIImage might *copy* the item, meaning that your instance will leak of you don't release it.

Comment: @drunknbass and @Jim, thank you, I am beginning to understand it now.

Answer (score 15):

## Do Not Call -retainCount

The number returned by retain count is the absolute retain count of the object.  There may be many retains in play that you have no control over as they are implementation details of the frameworks.  There are *always* better ways to validate your code's memory management.

Retain counts should only be considered as deltas;  if you cause a retain count to increase, you must cause it to be decreased.

Given:

```
UIImage* getSubImage(UIImage* uim, CGRect rc){
  CGImageRef imref  = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(uim.CGImage, rc); 
  UIImage*   sub = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imref];
  CGImageRelease(imref);
    NSLog(@"subimage retainCount=%d", [sub  retainCount]); // is 1
  return sub;
}//getSubImage
```

`imageWithCGImage:` returns an autoreleased object.   The retain count is irrelevant in that `imageWithCGImage:` might internally be doing any number of things -- caching, etc. -- that might influence the retain count.

`get*` is an odd pattern to use in Cocoa programming.  You just don't see that much.

I'd suggest something like:

```
- (UIImage *) subImage: (UIImage *) anImage inRect: (CGRect) aRect
{
      CGImageRef imageRef  = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(anImage.CGImage, aRect); 
      UIImage*   subImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];
      CGImageRelease(imageRef);
      return subImage;
}
```

Comment: @ragnarius "get" is typically used when the caller of function is responsible for it(releasing etc) so in this context it seems wrong, and would confuse anyone who maintained that code at first glance.

Comment: @drunknbass "get" is the opposite-- it returns something which is owned by the receiver, not the caller. "new" or "copy" or "alloc" return items which are implicitly retained on behalf of the caller. Check the CoreFoundation APIs for examples; CFURLCopyPath() returns a new CFStringRef which the caller must release, but CFArrayGetValueAtIndex() just returns an item which needs no management by the caller.

Comment: according to http://c.crap.ps/3n6N you would use get prefix on functions which pass in variables which could be mutated/modified. I have actually seen many people using it in different ways but most end up with an object that is not autoreleased.

Answer (score 6):

There is a naming convention for memory management. **All** Cocoa codes follow this rule:

[Basic Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1)

I strongly recommend you read this document and follow the rule too. The naming rule is part of the Cocoa too.

From the reference documentation:

> You own any object you create. You
>   “create” an object using a method
>   whose name begins with “alloc” or
>   “new” or contains “copy” (for example,
>   alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).
>
> You must relinquish ownership of
>   objects you own when you’re finished
>   with them. You relinquish ownership of
>   an object by sending it a release
>   message or an autorelease message
>   (autorelease is discussed in more
>   detail in “Autorelease”). In Cocoa
>   terminology, relinquishing ownership
>   of an object is therefore typically
>   referred to as “releasing” an object.

There is similar rule for C functions of Core Foundation framework. However there is no such autorelease-like things. You have to clarify everything on your documentation if you want to make Objective-C object with C functions.

And this might be helpful to you:
[imageWithCGImage and memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402148/imagewithcgimage-and-memory)

Comment: +1 Okay, I "own" the imref object and therefore I call CGImageRelease. I do not "own" the sub object and therefore I do not call release and I may conclude that it is already in the autoReleasePool.

Comment: @ragnarius exactly. :)  Once you really internalize these simple rules of ownership, memory management becomes a *lot* easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
  CGImageRelease(imref);
    NSLog(@"subimage retainCount=%d", [sub  retainCount]); // is 1
  return sub;
```

Because your method doesn't have the keyword alloc, retain, copy..., you have to autorelease the UIImage before returning it. But the factory method of the UIImage already did that for you. Beware that even you autorelease the sub, the retain count is still 1

Comment: The method that sends the `alloc` message needs to release or autorelease the object. In the case of the factory method, that's the method that sent `alloc`, so that's the method that sends `autorelease`. That said, don't worry about other classes' implementations—your own responsibilities are clearly specified, and all you need to do is follow them.