# Try to save image in background

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to call `UIImagePNGRepresentation` in other than main thread, but I'm getting only the EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

Here is code

```
UIImage *imageToSave = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

dispatch_queue_t taskQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(taskQ,
               ^{
                   NSData *binaryImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSave);

                   if (![binaryImage writeToFile:destinationFilePath atomically:YES]) {
                       SCASSERT(assCodeCannotCreateFile, @"Write of image file failed!");
                   };
               });
```

Exception occours when trying to access imageToSave variable.

EDIT:
I want to save OpenGL sceene to PNG file, there is code of whole function

```
- (void)saveImage:(NSString *)destinationFilePath {

NSUInteger width  = (uint)self.frame.size.width;
NSUInteger height = (uint)self.frame.size.height;

NSUInteger myDataLength = width * height * 4;

// allocate array and read pixels into it.
GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *)malloc(myDataLength);
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

// gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
// there's gotta be a better way, but this works.
GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *)malloc(myDataLength);

for (int y = 0; y <height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x <width * 4; x++) {
        buffer2[((int)height - 1 - y) * (int)width * 4 + x] = buffer[y * 4 * (int)width + x];
    }
}

JFFree(buffer);

// make data provider with data.
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, myDataLength, NULL);

// prep the ingredients
int bitsPerComponent = 8;
int bitsPerPixel = 32;
int bytesPerRow = 4 * width;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

// make the cgimage
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(width, 
                                    height, 
                                    bitsPerComponent, 
                                    bitsPerPixel,
                                    bytesPerRow,
                                    colorSpaceRef,
                                    bitmapInfo,
                                    provider,
                                    NULL,
                                    NO,
                                    renderingIntent);

UIImage *imageToSave = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

dispatch_queue_t taskQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(taskQ,
               ^{
                   NSData *binaryImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSave);

                   if (![binaryImage writeToFile:destinationFilePath atomically:YES]) {
                       SCASSERT(assCodeCannotCreateFile, @"Write of image file failed!");
                   };
               });

// release resources
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
JFFree(buffer2);
}
```

Comment: check whether your imageToSave is nil ???

Comment: Are you using ARC or not?

Comment: I'm using ARC, imageToSave is not nil. It is UIImage object. I checked

Comment: does it work when you are on the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

leave out the CGImageRelease call because the UIImage doesnt retain the CGImageRef

see [imageWithCGImage and memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402148/imagewithcgimage-and-memory)

Comment: yes this was it. When I moved all releasing code after "// release resources" inside `dispatch_async` it worked. Thanks for help