# Memory Leak iOS (UIImageView,UIImage,CGImage) not freed on ARC

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uiimageview, uiimage, automatic-ref-counting

Im trying to implement a simple video stream but for some reason my memory won't get freed:

```
(void)updateImage:(UIImage *)image{
  self.indicator.hidden = TRUE;
  //CGImageRelease([self.imageView.image CGImage]);
  self.imageView.image = nil;
  self.imageView.image = image;
  [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

If I use

```
CGImageRelease([self.imageView.image CGImage]);
```

memory will be freed. But when I return to a previous view controller the app will crash as it tries to free the allocated memory for that image, which I already freed. This method is called from a async task which creates an image using:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CFRelease(data);
```

As I understood it the UIImage now owns the CGImage and I shouldn't have to release it.
So is there anyway to ensure that the UIImage is freed when I updated the UIImageView with a new image?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402148/imagewithcgimage-and-memory (take a look I think it will be very helpful)

Comment: Yes, to some extent. My problem is however that the UIImage is not released. I take care as suggest in the thread and release the CGImage as you can see in the above code. Maybe my question is a little unclear, please let me know if that is the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok so I finally figured out the problem.

As I said I was using some background thread to perform the image update, the solution was to add it as a autorelease pool as following:

```
   @autoreleasepool {
        [self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateImage:) withObject:[self fetchImage] waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
```

Comment: I think that the autoreleasepool is overdone. The really important issue is the performSelectorOnMainThread, so the memory is freed in the proper thread

Comment: @Karsten: Without knowing what fetchImage does you can't make the assumption that the `@autoreleasepool` is unnecessary.